# Most efficient way to stop running a part of code

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

I am coding a personal assitant in Python. At this moment, I am planning all the things I am going to do but I have come up with a problem that I can't solve.

I will be running a main script that will check if user says `'Hello'` every 3 seconds. If he does so, then it should start running another script/function and stop the current one. After the task is performed it should start running again the main script (I will be using different scripts for each task to make it cleaner). I had thought about a while loop but I am not sure if this is the best option.

Comment: you could look into starting a sub process 
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['python', 'myscript'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: Based on this question and your profile, I would recommend undertaking something slightly less ambitious. Not in the sense of giving up on your project, which seems very neat and probably worthwhile, but in the sense of breaking it down into smaller tasks that you can actually teach yourself how to do. I can tell you that multiple processes are very well supported in Python, but that a while loop may not be an ideal option here (although it's probably not too bad, depending on the actual program). But that won't help you much right now.

Comment: A major part of coding is good design. With a good design, you can code up a personal assistant, starting as a beginner (you won't be a beginner when you're done). A big part of good design is figuring out how to break everything into manageable chunks that play well together. If you can do that, you can start learning what you need to get each component working, rather than trying to fit a while python textbook into one answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I guess you are right. I am a beginner, so this is an idea I had come up with recently. I will break the project into small pieces as you have said, then, whenever I am ready, I will go for it.

Comment: @Gerard. Good luck. It's a good project and you'll learn a lot. I suspect you'll end up writing lots of useful things along the way if you stick with it.

Comment: It's better if you ask multiple questions as multiple posts.  That said, the second question is too vague to get useful responses.  I suggest looking up natural language processing.

Comment: May I ask you something which is not releated to the post? Since I started I am wondering whether professional programmers have everything on their mind or they tend to look into the documentation. For example, the code you need to connect to a database and enter a value or the one you need to send a mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`select`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/select.html#select.select) system call is the a very efficient way to wait until a file is ready to be read before doing something:

```
import select
import sys

while True:
    reads, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 3)
    if reads:
        line = reads[0].readline()
        if line.strip().lower() == "hello":
            # do a thing
            print("hi")
```

Once `hello` is read, and your function or process is executed, your program will return to reading `stdin`.

Note that this works for POSIX systems but not for Windows (except for sockets).

Comment: This seems to work in Ubuntu but not in Windows (except for sockets), so it would be nice to specify it.